# Sort a list of lists by minimum value

Tags: c#, list, linq

I am trying to sort the lists inside a list by their minimum integer value. This is where I am at so far.

```
var SortedList = from lists in List 
                 orderby lists.List.Min(Min=>Min.value) 
                 ascending
                 select list ;
```

For example:

```
var x = new List<int>{ 5, 10, 4, 3, 0 };
var y = new List<int> { 4, -1, -5, 3, 2 };
var z = new List<int> { 3, 1, 0, -2, 2 };

var ListofLists = new List<List<int>> {x, y, z};
```

The output of my Linq shall be, to sort the lists by the minimum value in the list of lists. The sequence for the Lists in my example would be:

y -> z -> x

I have tried a lot of linq expressions and searched through the web. The question seems to be very simple... Thanks for any kind of help!

Comment: What should happen in case of duplicates ?

Comment: you have an extra `List<` in the declaration of `ListofLists`.

Comment: In my application there are no minimum duplicates possible.

Comment: In the case of possible ties(repeated elements) this question gets much more complex, especially if you want an efficient solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's as easy as:

```
var sorted = ListofLists.OrderBy(l => l.Min());
```

Or, if you prefer query syntax, you should do:

```
var sorted = from list in ListofLists 
             orderby list.Min()
             select list;
```

Here it is in action: https://dotnetfiddle.net/bnfGOG

Comment: Are there guarantees that `Enumerable.OrderBy()` extract keys only once? I couldn't find any in official [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @LeonidVasilyev Me neither. But After doing some tests (replacing `l.Min()` with `{Console.WriteLine("."); return l.Min();}`) it appears to be so. I get as meny dots in the output as there are lists to sort (tried with 3, 7 and 10 lists).